# Не отображаются изображения php mvc

Tags: php, html, mvc

Не могу понять почему не отображаются изображения. В любой части кода они не отображаются. Путь к изображениям верный. Картинки с интернета выводит :(
https://github.com/lordSerega/myBlog

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xl-12">
            <img src="пресс.jpg" alt="">
            <div class="card-deck">


<?php foreach ($this->posts as $key => $value) {?>


                    <div class="card">
                        <img src="пресс.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="sdfs">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title"><?=$value['title']?></h5>
                            <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted"><?=$value['postDate']?></small></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

    <?php
}?>


                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Путь указан относительно файла posts.php - как его вызываешь: напрямую или через require? Попробуй прописать путь от корневой папки

Comment: Через панель разработчика(вкладка Network) посмотрите, что у вас с путями к изображениям происходит. PS. И сразу замечу, что названия файлов у Вас на русском языке.

Comment: `<img src="/tpl/пресс.jpg" alt="">`